# Explorer crashed while moving files to external drive, amount of free space after that is wrong

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, data-recovery, disk-space, bittorrent

During the weekend something strange happened, which I don't understand.
Maybe somebody smarter than me can help me out here.

Last weekend I had the idea to move some movie files from my internal D drive (WD Green 2 TB) to an external drive (WD My Book 6 TB), because my D drive was getting full.
At that time according to Windows, I had only 7 GB left on my D drive. I've checked it by right clicking on the drive and saw how many space was left.

The movies are actually episodes from a serie. I selected 3 folders (= 3 seasons) which was approx 240 GB.
During the moving of the files (I did cut and paste in Windows Explorer) I was updating some software on my pc. Maybe not the smartest thing to do, but I thought what can go wrong...
Including the software WD Discovery, which is used by my external drive. I figured what can go wrong at this point, because I'm not actually using the software at the moment, just cut and paste.

All of a sudden, all my Windows of Windows Explorer closed themselves, the taskbar vanished and reappeared in a matter of seconds.
Because of this action the window of the transferring files to the external drive was gone! So, I figured it has just stopped moving files to my external drive.

Season 1 was almost completely on my external drive, expect for 1 video file. Seasons 2 and 3 still remained on the D drive.

Now, it's getting interesting. Like I've said, the 3 folders where approx 240 GB in total.
Each folder was approx 80 GB big. So, you would expect that the free space on the D drive would be increased with only 80 GB. So, if you know that in the beginning I had only 7 GB left, you would think I now have 87 GB free space. Wrong!
For some reason, which I don't understand Windows says I now have 250 GB free space on my D drive.
How is this possible if only 80 GB were moved?
What happened here? Is this a malfunction in Windows?
Did I really loose 250 GB, or more likely 170 GB (250 GB - 80 GB = 170 GB).

Edit:
One thing else got me puzzled. When I go to "Settings", "System", "Storage", "Storage for other station" then I select the D drive and I see next to "Temp files" 232 GB!!
I don't have anything installed on my D drive, expect for games from Steam.
But the weird thing is, when I click on this, it's saying in the next window that I only have 711 MB in the Recycle bin. Where is all of those 232 GB gone to?

One other thing, got me thinking, the movies where originally downloaded through torrent-files. I've seen that size of the other seasons (which I don't fully have) are showing different file sizes.
Could it be, that perhaps, before the crash, Windows was showing a faulty free disk space? And that now with the crash the real free space is been shown? Or isn't that possible?

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the folders that failed to transfer - actually tried playing the files? Cut/paste on Windows is notoriously flaky if interrupted.

Comment: Yes, I did. All the files seems to be playing okay.

Comment: BTW, next time, you might try MS Robocopy, for *robust* (and efficient) copying tasks: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Will do from now on :)

Comment: The main question for me is... how can I actually know if I lost some data?
And if so, would it be only in the folder I was moving the files from one location to another??

Comment: Nobody who can help me? :(